# Are there infinitely many real quadratic number fields with unique factorization?

Tags: prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

Unique factorization is a commutative ring in which every non-zero non-unit element can be written as a product of prime elements (or irreducible elements), uniquely up to order and units.

I'm struggling with understanding and proving this. A bonus question posed by one of my professors.

Comment: No one knows, that's an open problem.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is so far unsolved, your professor probably wanted to see if he could create a new Good Will Hunting.